# create mono and stereo stream in the same file with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a film with 2 mono audio stream of avi file.

I would like to create a third file, with one stereo stream from the 2 mono stream, and one mono stream, addition of the 2 monos audio source...
here's the code to make mono stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi-ac 1 mono.avi
```

here's the code to make an stereo stream from 2 mono stream:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi-filter_complex "[0:1][0:2] amerge=inputs=2" -c:a pcm_s16le output.avi
```

How could I merge those 2codes to make one audio file with one stero track, and one mono track ? 
tiouss ! thanks in advance

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't write polytrack WAVs. Will other formats like MOV or MKV do?

Comment: Hi !
I can write polytrack movie with avi...
I should have said thait it's for movie..thanks for your response !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

really cool !! This does work: (apparently ffmpeg doesn't like when you use the same label twice):

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -filter_ complex "[0:1][0:2]amerge=inputs=2[stereo]"
  -map "[stereo]" -filter_complex "[0: 1][0:2]amerge=inputs=2[formono]"
 -map "[formono]" -ac:a:1 1 -c:a pcm_s16le -map 0:v -c:v copy out.avi
```

Thank you so much Mulvya for your precious help!!!!

Comment: There is no reason to ever use more than one `-filter_complex`.

Comment: I can not use twice stereo label...
It gives me: 
Output with label 'stereo' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi
  -filter_complex "[0:1][0:2]amerge=inputs=2[stereo]"
  -map "[stereo]" -map "[stereo]" -ac:a:1 1 -c:a pcm_s16le output.avi
```

Video, is any, is ignored. Add `-map 0:v -c:v copy` if video has to be preserved.

Comment: thanks !!
but unfortunately the mono stream is just silent...
could you explain your code a little bit..to try to debug it...thanks !!